# Rule not recognized in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I have a basic makefile to compile C files necessary for compiling a shared library, I have an error because the makefile is not recognized:

```
 SOURCES=/home/test/project/sources
 OBJECTS=/home/test/project/objects

 $(OBJECTS)/%.o:$(SOURCES)/%.c
 $(CC) -fPIC -c $^ -o $@

 sharedlib: $(OBJECTS)/%.o
 $(CC) -shared -o libsharedlib.so $<
```

When I run make I get that there is no rule for target: `$(OBJECTS)/%.o` needed by `sharedlib`. While the rule is written right before sharedlib.

Comment: But wildcard would mean that I compile all files at once ?

Comment: I have changed it but still the same issue.

Comment: Are you trying to compile libsharedlib.so with all objects at once?

Comment: Yes. the second rule is for getting all object files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that nowhere you are *explicitly* telling make what your source files are. Start by doing that:

```
SOURCEDIR=/home/test/project/sources
SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
```

Then, derive the object file names from the source file names by substituting `.c` for `.o`:

```
OBJECTDIR=/home/test/project/objects
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

You can still keep your generic rule to build object files:

```
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c
        $(CC) -fPIC -c $^ -o $@
```

But you give the explicit list of object files to the rule to make `sharedlib`:

```
libsharedlib.so: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -shared -o $@ $<
```

Note that I made the name of the rule the same as the file that is being generated. That's important, because calling make twice in a row will then skip building the library a second time. You can always add an alias if you want:

```
sharedlib: libsharedlib.so
```

In that case, it's also good to tell make that `sharedlib` is not a real file:

```
.PHONY sharedlib
```

This prevents weird things from happening if you ever did have a file called `sharedlib` in the directory.

Comment: One additional problem and that is when I call make on the target ´$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o´: I get no rule to make target ´$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o´ ? Could you please tell me why ? basically, makefile does not execute the rule ´$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c´ when make is called on target sharedlib.

Comment: @Bionix1441: because there is no rule that is literally `$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o`. That is just a *pattern*, and you have to provide make with a real filename that matches the pattern before it uses that rule.

Comment: you are right. finally I can compile with no problems

Answer (score 1):

The library rule

```
sharedlib: $(OBJECTS)/%.o
```

is not enough to tell Make which objs are needed for the library.

This should work, and gives explicit control on which are the sources/objs pairs you want in the library:

```
SOURCESDIR=/home/test/project/sources
OBJECTDIR=/home/test/project/objects

OBJLIST = \
    $(OBJECTS)/file1.o \
    $(OBJECTS)/file2.o

$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCESDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $^ -o $@

sharedlib: $(OBJLIST)
    $(CC) -shared -o libsharedlib.so $<
```

Comment: I just noticed that that the suggestions about the library rule in the answer above by G Sliepen are very appropriate

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.